# Iterating through numpy array for use in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a project where I'm trying to update a dataframe to a new set of changes being rolled out. There are currently 15,000 data samples in the dataframe, so runtime can become an issue quickly. I know vectorizing a dataframe using numpy is a good way to cut back on runtime, but I'm running into an issue with my numpy array and dictionary.

The goal is to look at the value in `col3`, use that as the key to `df_dict`, and use the value of that dictionary entry to multiply to `col2` and assign to `col1`.

I've been able to do this using for loops, but it runs into a serious problem of runtime - especially because there are more steps involved than just what I'm asking for help on.

```
d = {"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4], "col2": [1, 2, 3, 4], "col3": ["a","b","c","d"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_dict = {"a":1.2,"b":1.5,"c":0.95,"d":1.25}

df["col1"]=df["col2"].values*df_dict[df["col3"].values]
```

I expect `col1` to be updated to `[1.2, 3, 2.85, 5]`, but instead I get the error 
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

I get why the error occurs, I just want to find the best alternative.

Comment: `df["col1"]=df["col2"]* [df_dict.get(i, 1) for i in df["col3"].values]` ?

Comment: The dictionary lookup has to be done one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little better solution using `.map`.

So replace:

```
df["col1"]=df["col2"].values*df_dict[df["col3"].values]
```

With:

```
df["col1"]=df["col2"] * df['col3'].map(df_dict)
```

Comment: Looks like this `map` works by first converting the dictionary into a Series, `pd.Series(df_dict)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
d = {"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4], "col2": [1, 2, 3, 4], "col3": ["a","b","c","d"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_dict = {"a":1.2,"b":1.5,"c":0.95,"d":1.25}

df["col1"]=df["col2"]* [df_dict.get(i, 1) for i in df["col3"]]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   col1  col2 col3
0  1.20     1    a
1  3.00     2    b
2  2.85     3    c
3  5.00     4    d
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! is this the most runtime-optimized way, considering it is still doing base python loops?